# Bedeutung von "Dickbrettbohrerfach"

Tags: single-word-request

Ein [einleitendes Buch](http://www.amazon.de/gp/offer-listing/3834819360/ref=sr_1_fkmr0_1_olp?ie=UTF8&qid=1414398566&sr=8-1-fkmr0&keywords=Keine+Panik+Vor+Thermodynamik!%3A+Erfolg+Und+Spab+Im+Klassischen+%22Dickbrettbohrerfach%22+Des+Ingenieurstudiums&condition=new) in die Thermodynamik heißt *Keine Panik vor Thermodynamik!: Erfolg und Spaß im klassischen "Dickbrettbohrerfach" des Ingenieurstudiums*
Ich verstehe die buchstäbliche Bedeutung von "Dickbrettbohrerfach" aber ich nehme an, dass hier eine scherzhafte Anspielung vorliegt. Welche?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Die Wortschöpfung „Dickbrettbohrer…“ soll sicherlich den Gegensatz zum umgangssprachlichen Wort „Dünnbrettbohrer“ ausdrücken.

> **Dünnbrettbohrer,** der (ugs. abwertend):
>
> **a)** nicht besonders intelligenter Mensch;
>
> **b)** jmd., der bei der Bewältigung einer Aufgabe den Weg des geringsten Widerstandes geht.

aus *Duden – Deutsches Universalwörterbuch,* 5. Aufl. Mannheim 2003

Comment: Sehr interessant, Loong:  das Wort "Dünnbrettbohrer" (dass ich natürlich nicht kannte) ist sehr bildlich und amüsant. Vielen Dank für deine rasche Antwort.

Comment: Das wusste ich in der Tat auch nicht. @GeorgesElencwajg: Akzeptierst du die Antwort?

Comment: Prinzipiell möchte ich Antworten nur nach wenigstens 24 Stunden akzeptieren, um gegenüber den anderen potenziellen Benutzeren fair zu bleiben.

Comment: @Georges Elencwajg Du kannst die Frage akzeptieren, wann du willst. Aber die akzeptierte Frage soll nicht unbedingt die beste, lustigste odrr sonstwie bemerkenswert sein. Wenn sie deine Frage beantwortet, ist sie akzeptabel. Irgendjemandem wird sicher noch etwas einfallen,  aber das braucht eine Frage- und Antwort-Seite nicht.

Answer (score 3):

Ich denke, es geht direkter als in der akzeptierten Antwort: Sicherlich ist die Assoziation mit den "Dünnbrettbohrern" nicht falsch. Allerdings gibt es eine eigenständige Redewendung "dicke Bretter bohren", die bedeutet, dass man sich sehr anstrengen und sehr ausdauernd sein muss, um ein Ergebnis zu erzielen. Insbesondere im Zusammenhang mit *Keine Panik vor Thermodynamik!: Erfolg und Spaß [...]* ist genau dies gemeint: Keine Angst vor dem Fach Thermodynamik, zu dessen Verständnis man normalerweise dicke Bretter bohren muss.

Eine Google-Suche ergibt viele Ergebnisse für diese Redewendung, inklusive [Wikipedia](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liste_deutscher_Redewendungen).

Comment: Danke für den interessanten Beitrag Oguk